# VNC Server + no monitor + reboot = blank screen in VNCViewer until monitor is attached

Tags: windows-7, vnc

I am running RealVNC Server free on a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 machine.  The server machine has an ATI Radeon 57xx series graphics card and no onboard video.  I intend for this machine to not use a monitor and most of the time it does not have a monitor plugged in.

If the server is rebooted, and then a VNC Viewer connects, authentication (vnc password) succeeds and the VNC viewer window displays a black screen in a resolution different from the server's desktop resolution.  At this point, the only way to get the VNC viewer to display the desktop is to physically connect the server machine's DVI input to a monitor.  ***Interestingly enough, the display does not need to be connected to any power source.***

At this point, the VNC Viewer window will display the desktop of the server without any further action, and function normally.  The DVI connection from the server to the display can be immediately unplugged.

The advantage of being able to run VNC Server as a service is, in this case, negated by the fact that I have to plug it into a physical display every time the machine is rebooted for software changes, windows updates, etc.

To fix this I have tried every 'update method' setting on the server, with no luck.  I am seeking a solution that allows clients to interact with the server's desktop without the need for physical intervention at the server.

Comment: Have you tried just hooking up a video cable not connected to a monitor?

Comment: Good suggestion, I forgot to mention that I've been doing this and it does not help at all, there must be a monitor at the other end of the cable (although it can be unplugged from AC power).

Comment: Is there a reason you use VNC over RDP?  RDP doesn't require a monitor plugged in.

Comment: have you checked this? https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/277/6/im-getting-a-black-screen-when-i-connect-to-vnc-server

Comment: `CaptureMethod = 1` works with RealVNC